# Why jar can not be deployed on Apache tomcat or any other application server?

Tags: java, tomcat

Questions was asked in interview that can we deploy jar on tomcat?
My answer was no, so counter was why like so.

Kindly help

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's pretty clear he what is he asking. This close vote makes no sense.

Comment: Sure you can, but what do you expect to happen?

Comment: It was just an interview question asked to me that  can we do it, my answer was no we can not, so interviewer countered that if not then why like that???

Answer (score 1):

To deploy it succesfully, you have to create a `war` file instead of a `jar`. See the differences:

- `jar` (Java archive) contains libraries, resources a accessories files.
- `war` (Web archive) contains the web application deployable on any servlet/server
- `ear` (Enterprise archive) is all above can be packaged deployed on any server/servlet as well

I don't know the background of your development. In case you use `Maven`, just change the packaging.

```
<project>  
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>exampleProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1</version>
    ....
</project>
```

---

In the interview you'd simply answer that the purpose of `jar` is not to be deployed on Tomcat. There is `war` for it. Moreover `war` contains the web-content like HTML, CSS, JavaScript, JSP, images etc..

Answer (score 1):

you can not deploy jar in a stand alone Tomcat container, but it is possible to deploy web application as executable jar in embedded Tomcat (example - using Spring boot with embedded tomcat as container)